# Grails: Get the View name in the Layout GSP

Tags: grails, layout, view, gsp

With Grails, is it possible to get the name of the view that is being rendered while in the layout GSP file?  I'd like to change one minor thing in the layout file depending on which view is going to be rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If found this to be rather difficult to determine. It's easy if you use conventions, but you can always explicitly render any view you want. See the code in [How to detect which view file has been rendered in grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19592838/how-to-detect-which-view-file-has-been-rendered-in-grails) for how to determine this in a filter.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the view is normally the same as the action that has just been executed (e.g. `show` action normally renders the `show.gsp` view) - if this is the case in your view, then you can get it in your layout gsp using `${actionName}`.

Comment: And what if you have code like `render view: 'foo', model: ...` ?

Comment: Nice tip. And you can get the controller with ${actionController}.